# C++ draw rectangle position

Tags: c++, position, draw

I have my class:

```
class Rectangle : public TwoDim
{
public:
    void fun() {};
    void printShape();
    Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int height1, int width1)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        height = height1;
        width = width1;

    }

};
```

And the function to print it:

```
void Rectangle::printShape()
{
    {

        cout << "+";
        for (int i = 0; i <  width - 2; i++)
        {
            cout << "-";
        }
        cout << "+\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
        {
            cout << "|";
            for (int j = 0; j < +width - 2; j++)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << "|\n";
        }

        cout << "+";
        for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; i++)
        {
            cout << "-";
        }
        cout << "+\n";
    }

}
```

How do I change my function such that I will draw the rectangle starting from the point `(x, y)`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Point (x,y) relative to what?  You mean you want to add some `"\n"` and `" "` characters to change the output?  Or if you want a specific position on the terminal or window, you'll need to use OS-specific library, not just core C++.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Have you tried?  Got some code that doesn't quite work that we can look at?

Comment: @dgnorton I have tried, it is a homework, but I am too noob to do that :(

Comment: @aschepler, I want to add some \n and spaces

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by outputting `y` `std::endl`s before the actual printing, and then outputting `x` `" "` before effectively printing each row.

Comment: You don't need to flush the output `y` times.

Comment: @aschepler unless it's proven by profiling that it's not doable, I'd rather have this than a bunch of `"\n"`s concatenated together.

Comment: @Luchian: Why?  (And I should think you'd use `'\n'`, the character and not the string)

Comment: @BenVoigt personal preference.

Comment: I recently read a rant about overuse of `std::endl` and it made sense to me.  I guess it's really just a piece in the balance of don't-waste-time-on-premature-optimization versus do-think-about-what-the-code-means.